# Django Forms replacement for Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I am looking for a Django Forms replacement.

I need auto-build form based on GAE Model as in Django.
Django Forms work with some bugs on GAE. And I need to replace it.

I have found WTForms. What is your choice?

Comment: You might want to explain just why you don't want to use Django forms.

Comment: Django Forms have a many problems if we build forms based on models. For example, request dictionary in Django and webob - presented in different types of data, and this is raise validation errors. I need more easy component to build forms from models more easy, and without unexpected situations.

Comment: So you want another form library that lets you build forms based on App Engine models? If not, why not just use Django forms without the model integration?

Answer (score 2):

[WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) is a good choice on GAE. It is similar to django forms.

Also note, other than the `ModelForms` and the related types, `django-forms` should work quite well on the GAE, out of the box. In fact, that is one of the reason why django is even supported on GAE, in the first place.

Comment: But I have some issues with Django Forms. For example, if I have worked with related fields than this creates some troubles. (Now I can't say what bugs I see in the past). Now I search tool to work correctly on GAE. And I can extend some field types easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for an answer to this as well.. And the only thing i can find is WTForms. WTForms comes with some integration towards translating models into forms. To be more specific, it has something called model_form found in wtforms.appengine.ext.model_form. With this you can make a form wit

```
form_obj = model_form(ModelClass)

#validate with
form = form_obj(request.POST)
if form.validate()
    mc = ModelClass
    form.populate_obj(mc)
    mc.put()
```

It doesnt support the new ndb-module jet. But most stuff works with small code-changes.. Hope it helps.

Comment: P.S. The code-example isnt plugable.. the populate_obj() can be found in the form-file in wtforms root